# C error deferencing pointer to incomplete type Binary tree

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I am writing a C library to manage binary tree and I get error "deferencing pointer to incomplete type" and I'm not sure how to fix that. Here's my code:

```
typedef struct bintree {
    int val;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
} bintree;
```

and code to create tree:

```
bintree* createbintree(bintree * tree, int val) {
    if (tree->val == NULL)
        tree->val = val;
    else if (val < tree->val)
        if (tree->left != NULL)
            insert(tree->left, val);
        else {
            tree->left = malloc(sizeof(bintree));
            tree->left->val = val;
        }  //error occur here
    else if (val >= tree->val)
        if (tree->right != NULL)
            insert(tree->right, val);
        else {
            tree->right = malloc(sizeof(bintree));
            tree->right->val = val;
        }  //and also here
}
```

I'm not quite sure how I am supposed to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple errors:

- you are accessing field `val` of `bintree` while it's declared as `value`
- a `bintree` contains pointers to `struct node*` but that type is not defined anywhere (and that's causing your error)